# How prevent that an user redistribute an ios inhouse application?

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution

Lot of authorized users will install the app. For example one of them with a jailbroken device can redistribute the IPA binary. Any idea to prevent this?

TestFlight.com blocks some installations. Do you know what are they doing?

Comment: No matter what you try, someone will eventually find a way around your restrictions.

Comment: Simply create an authentication system inside your app. You can only limit installation to certain devices for development proposes, if you are using an enterprise profile anyone can install, thats way an authentication system would work best.

Comment: Thanks. It's true, there isn't other way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an in-house app, it will be limited to devices on your provisioning profile (unless you're using an enterprise one).